# How to implement a Hyperparameter using a MNIST dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter, knn

I am currently running a program in Jupyter notebook to classify MNIST dataset.
 I am trying to use the KNN classifier to do this and it is taking more than an hour to run. I am new to classifiers and hyper-parameters and there does not seem to be any decent tutorials on how to properly implement one of them. Could anyone give me some tips on how to use a hyper-parameter for this classification? I have searched and seen GridSearchCv and RandomizedSearchCV. From viewing their examples it seems they select different attribute names and alter to the ones necessary for their code. I do not understand how this can be done for MNIST dataset if the data is just handwritten digits. Seeing that there is only digits could there not be a need for a hyperparameter in this case? This is my code that I am currently still running. Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
# To support both python 2 and python 3
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals

# Common imports
import numpy as np
import os

# to make this notebook's output stable across runs
np.random.seed(42)

# To plot pretty figures
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 14
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12

# Where to save the figures
PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = "."
CHAPTER_ID = "classification"

def save_fig(fig_id, tight_layout=True):
    image_dir = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "images", CHAPTER_ID)
    if not os.path.exists(image_dir):
        os.makedirs(image_dir)

    path = os.path.join(image_dir, fig_id + ".png")
    print("Saving figure", fig_id)
    if tight_layout:
        plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(path, format='png', dpi=300)
def sort_by_target(mnist):
    reorder_train = np.array(sorted([(target, i) for i, target in enumerate(mnist.target[:60000])]))[:, 1]
    reorder_test = np.array(sorted([(target, i) for i, target in enumerate(mnist.target[60000:])]))[:, 1]
    mnist.data[:60000] = mnist.data[reorder_train]
    mnist.target[:60000] = mnist.target[reorder_train]
    mnist.data[60000:] = mnist.data[reorder_test + 60000]
    mnist.target[60000:] = mnist.target[reorder_test + 60000]
try:
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
    mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, cache=True)
    mnist.target = mnist.target.astype(np.int8) # fetch_openml() returns targets as strings
    sort_by_target(mnist) # fetch_openml() returns an unsorted dataset
except ImportError:
    from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
    mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
    mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
mnist.data.shape
X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
X.shape
y.shape

#select and display some digit from the dataset
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

some_digit_index = 7201
some_digit = X[some_digit_index]
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)
plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap = matplotlib.cm.binary,
           interpolation="nearest")
plt.axis("off")

save_fig("some_digit_plot")
plt.show()

#print some digit's label
print('The ground truth label for the digit above is: ',y[some_digit_index])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
#random shuffle
import numpy as np

shuffle_index = np.random.permutation(60000)
X_train, y_train = X_train[shuffle_index], y_train[shuffle_index]
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

y_train_large = (y_train >= 7)
y_train_odd = (y_train % 2 == 1)
y_multilabel = np.c_[y_train_large, y_train_odd]

knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn_clf.fit(X_train, y_multilabel)
knn_clf.predict([some_digit])

y_train_knn_pred = cross_val_predict(knn_clf, X_train, y_multilabel, cv=3, n_jobs=-1)
f1_score(y_multilabel, y_train_knn_pred, average="macro")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular hyperparameter for KNN would be `n_neighbors`, that is, how many nearest neighbors you consider to assign a label to a new point. By default, it is set to 5, but it might not be the best choice. Therefore it is often better to find what the best choice is for your specific problem.

This is how you would find the optimal hyperparameter for your example:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = {"n_neighbors" : [3,5,7]}     

KNN=KNeighborsClassifier()

grid=GridSearchCV(KNN, param_grid = param_grid , cv = 5, scoring = 'accuracy', return_train_score = False)
grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

What this does is comparing the performance of your KNN model with the different values of `n_neighbors` that you set. Then when you do:

```
print(grid.best_score_)
print(grid.best_params_)
```

it will show you what the best performance score was, and for which choice of parameters it was achieved.

All this has nothing to do with the fact that you are using MNIST data. You could use this approach for any other classification task, as long as you think KNN might be a sensible choice for your task (which might be arguable for image classification). The only thing that would change from one task to another is the optimal value of the hyperparameters.

PS: I would advise not to use the `y_multilabel` terminology as this might refer to a specific classification task where each data point could have several labels, which is not the case in MNIST (each image represents only one digit at at time).

Comment: Thank you @MaximeKan it makes a bit more sense understanding the code. I agree there are other classifiers that would be best for this case, but for this task we want to just see the difference (running random forest as well) .

Comment: could you explain what the 3,5,7 represent in this case?

Comment: [3,5,7] is the list of all the different values I want the GridSearch algorithm to try out for n_neighbors. You can take whatever numbers you like (I just put these because it's centered around scikit learn's default value, which is 5)